# how to retrieve all cookies in c#?

Tags: c#, cookies, fiddler

According fiddler, I expect these cookies after logging

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=value; Version=1; Domain=.domain.com.mx; Path=/
Set-Cookie: saplb_*=value; Version=1; Path=/
Set-Cookie: PortalAlias=portal; Path=/
Set-Cookie: MYSAPSSO2=value;path=/;domain=.domain.com.mx;HttpOnly
```

Therefore, I just get this cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: PortalAlias=portal; Path=/
```

I have this code for login:

```
string url = "site.com";

string postdata = "user=username&pass=userpass";
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);


**// GET cookies from url
getCookies(url)**

// request
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.CookieContainer = this.cookies;

// post
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
using (Stream postdata_stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  postdata_stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


// response
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
  // here, I expect to receive 4 cookies, but I only get 1
  foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies) 
  {
    log("Name:" + c.Name);
    log("Value:" + c.Value);
    log("");
    this.cookies.Add(new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path, c.Domain));
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I check my program response in fiddler there are the 4 cookies, but do not why I can only read one.

**UPDATE**

Code added for cookies by GET:

```
private void getCookies(string url)
{

  // request
  HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequestObject(url);
  request.CookieContainer = this.cookies; // protected member

  request.Method = "GET";
  request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 irefox/10.0.2";

  // response
  using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  {
    foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
    {

        // add cookies to my CookieContainer
        this.cookies.Add(new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path, c.Domain));
    }
  }
}
```

With getCookies() I have 3/4 cookies:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=value; Version=1; Domain=.domain.com.mx; Path=/
Set-Cookie: saplb_*=value; Version=1; Path=/
Set-Cookie: PortalAlias=portal; Path=/
```

But still need a cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: MYSAPSSO2=value;path=/;domain=.domain.com.mx;HttpOnly
```

In addition, I compare the request with Fiddler/WinMerge:

```
// program request
$Version=1; saplb_*=value; $Path=/; $Version=1; JSESSIONID=value; $Path=/; Domain=.domain.com.mx
Expect: 100-continue

// firefox request
saplb_*=value; JSESSIONID=value
Connection: keep-alive
```

Why there is a "$" character in my request?

Answer (score 2):

Use Fiddler to compare the HTTP request you're making from code with one made from the browser.

To do that, select the two requests and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (you may have to configure the compare tool by following [these instructions](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/CompareTool.asp))

Also, try to examine all the requests initiated from the browser. It's possible that some of the cookies are received in a previous request (typically the GET request you make when you request the Login page). If needed, perform a GET first, collect the cookies and then do the POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
  {
    Response.Write(Request.Cookies[i].Name + " : ");
    Response.Write(Request.Cookies[i].Value);
    Response.Write("<br />");
  }
%>
```